# prompt with password in codeigniter using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

Admin delete teacher before doing this he required to re-enter password then delete teacher how can I delete this?

I try my best but when I add JavaScript code prompt is display but delete function not work. Anyone guide me where I'm going wrong?

**my code in view**:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url("admin");?>/teacher/delete/<?php echo $row['student_profile_id'];?>" class="confirm fa fa-trash-o" ></a></td>
```

**my Script**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e){
    bootbox.prompt({
        title: "Are You Sure Want To Delete Teacher ?,Enter Password",
        inputType: 'password',
        callback:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

this is confirmation of password but record not delete image

[image]

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but is your goal to post that password to the server and verify it server-side before you delete? If not anybody can press F12 and force that method to return true (or request that URL directly)

Answer (score 0):

you should create ajax function that will check if the user submit the correct password
then if the response is true

```
if(response == true){
   window.href = $(this).attr('href')
}
```

if your delete function is your href your can use the code above,

Comment: delete function worked but password not compared correct pls guide me                $(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e)
    {
     e.preventDefault();
     var lHref = $(this).attr('href');
      bootbox.prompt({
        title: "are u sure delete?Enter Password",
       inputType: 'password',
        callback:function(result) {
         if(result == true)
         {
          top.location.href = e.target.href;
         
         }
      
       
       } 
     }); 
     
        });